# How can we prevent python from automatically inserting space characters in print statements when we remember to insert a space ourselves?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

Pretend that "`.`" is a space character. Then, Python's print function behaves as follows:

```
   print("ham is", 5)    "ham.is.5"
   print("ham is ", 5)   "ham.is..5"
```

Python's `print` function always inserts spaces between adjacent objects.

We seek to write a function `sprint` having the following behavior:

```
   sprint("ham is", 5)    "ham.is.5"
   sprint("ham is ", 5)   "ham.is.5"
```

given `sprint(left, right)` we insert a space between `left` and `right` only if `left` ends in a white space char or `right` begins in a white-space char.

- `sprint` is required to accept any number of arguments, just like `print`.
- `sprint` is required to the keyword argument `end`, just like `print` does.
- `sprint` should be as much like `print` as possible, except the decision as to when to insert spaces.

Comment: That's not you remembering to insert a space; that's you forgetting not to insert it.

Answer (score 0):

The following code does the trick

```
import itertools as itts
import sys

def sprint(*args, **kwargs):
    """
   If you do *not* insert the space between strings, then sprint will insert one for you
        if you *do* insert the space, then sprint won't insert a space

    sprint("ham is", 5)    "ham.is.5"
    sprint("ham is ", 5)   "ham.is.5"

    sprint mostly behaves like print.
    However, unlike ....
        print("", end = "")
    we have ...
        sprint("", end = "")
    ... will cause an error
    """
    try:
        # suppose someone input a keyword argument for `end`
        # We wish to append that string to the end of `args`
        # if `end == "\t"`, then the new argument list will have
        # a tab character as the very last argument 
        args = itts.chain(args, itts.repeat(kwargs["end"], 1))

    except KeyError:

        # in this case, no keyword argument `end` was used
        # we append nothing to the end of `args`
        pass

    # convert everything into a string
    sargs = (str(x) for x in args)

    # sargs = filter out empty strings(sargs)
    sargs = filter(lambda x: x != "", sargs)

    try:
        while True:
            got_left = False
            left = next(sargs)
            got_left = True
            right = next(sargs)
            sprint_two(left, right)
    except StopIteration:
        if got_left:
            # if an odd number of arguments were received
            sprint_one(left)
    return None

def sprint_two(left, right):
    """
    print exactly two items, no more, and no less.
    """
    # assert (left and right are strings)
    assert(isinstance(left, str) and isinstance(right, str))

    # if (left ends in white space) or (right begins with white space)
    whitey = " \f\n\r\t\v"
    if (left[-1] in whitey) or (right[-1] in whitey):
        # print (left, right) without space char inserted in-between
        r = sprint_one(left, right)
    else:
        r = sprint_one(left, " ", right)
    return r

def sprint_one(*args):
    """
    PRECONDITION: all input arguments must be strings

    mainly wrote this function so that didn't have to repeatedly
    `sys.stdout.write(''.join(args))`, which looks very ugly 
    """
    sys.stdout.write(''.join(args))
```

Comment: this is a self-answered question. But this code is too complex to be useful, specially because there was no explanation.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre so would this be in the spirit of something like a community post?

Comment: no, self-answered question: posting a question and an answer at the same time. To share the knowledge Q&A-style.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I think that `C.Nivs` was joking. Most community posts have code which is too complex to be useful, and which is lacking in explanation. Thus, C.Nivs was stating that my post was much like community ones.